# How to cancel googleplay connection attempt when the device is offline?

Tags: java, android

I am doing an Android game application. My main activity extends BaseGamesActivity so it is connecting to google play by itself when you launch the apps. I want the game to be playable offline. Is there a way that the apps don't try to connect to google play when the device is not connected to internet?

Answer (score 0):

You can still try to connect to Google Play, just do something different (start offline play) if the connection fails.

```
int resp = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);

if(resp == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS){
    // Start online play
    /* actually connect to Google Play here */
}
else{
    // Start offline play
}
```

Comment: Yes but the thing is that I don' want this pop-up to appear: "Failed to sign in. Please check your network connection and try again."

Comment: You don't actually try to connect to Google Play until you go into the resp == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS portion of the if statement. resp just determines if you can actually connect, it doesn't try to connect. If you put your code for starting the game offline in the else statement it should be fine. I could be wrong, I don't have the means to test it right now, but will when I get a chance.

Comment: I understand what you mean. But I'm not explicitly connecting to google play. The class 'BaseGameActivity' does it. So even if I know the service is not available, I can't control that pop-up.

Comment: Any way you could point me to BaseGameActivity or the example you are using so I can get an idea of what is going on? You might be able to adjust some things in that class or use some sort of saved preferences or bundle to do a similar thing as I posted above.